# Installed google plugin for eclipse but see no web application project menu item

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I use standalone eclipse on linux. I downloaded it from eclipse site ( not from my distro's repository ) and extracted it to home folder. Installed google plugin for eclipse (using Help->Install New Software). But see no new Web Application Project menu item. When I create new java project, in project properties I can select on Google tab "Use google app engine" checkbox. But I have to create war folder, web.xml, appengine-web.xml, etc. So I want to get new web application project template. How do I turn it on?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that you downloaded "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers". Please delete your current Eclipse installation and download a new archive from http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigosr2